# The topology of spaces of immersed circles in the plane

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology

Whitney number (the turning number of the tangent) classifies the connected components of the space of immersed circles in the plane.

What is known about the topology of the connected components?

Comment: They are contractible by the Hirsch--Smale h-principle. I do not know about the exact topological description. I suppose that it is diffeomorphic to the tangent space to the space of immersions, which is $C^\infty(S^1, {\mathbb R}^2)$.